# Rc with zero references

Tags: rust, reference-counting

Am I able to create an `Rc` with zero (strong) references? How to do this?

I am doing references counting digraphs. An empty digraph would be represented as an `Rc` variable with zero references.

If it is impossible, I can use `Option<Rc>`, but that is inefficient and inconvenient.

Comment: It's impossible as follows from that `Rc::get_mut()` "Returns a mutable reference into the given Rc, if there are no other Rc or Weak pointers to the same allocation." (No case of zero references from our `Rc`.)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your use case, but it sounds like you may be trying to create a `Weak` that has no underlying allocation?  In which case, [`Weak::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html#method.new) does exactly that.

Comment: @eggyal No, `Weak` cannot hold real references, that is needed when I populate the digraph.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here.

Comment: @eggyal The problem is that I don't know how to do this and cannot create a good example.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that's possible with `Rc` on its own.

As for `Option<Rc>`, it might be a bit inconvenient, but I wouldn't say it's inefficient (in terms of performance and memory usage). Rust does a pretty good job in optimizing `Option`s. `Rc` is a smart pointer and the Rust compiler does so that an `Option` wrapped around a smart pointer doesn't use any extra memory. See this:

```
use std::mem::size_of;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", size_of::<Rc<i32>>());          // Prints "8"
    println!("{}", size_of::<Option<Rc<i32>>>());  // Prints "8"
}
```